# Title and author of a short story where Edgar Allan Poe's body is host to a time traveller's personality?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This short story is based on the premise that future time travellers take over people's bodies like puppets to experience life in the past. However, Poe's personality is so strong that the traveller is trapped within his body, unable to return. His repressed memories inspire Poe's fiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fellow over at "The Straight Dope" who calls himself "The Other Waldo Pepper" has ID'd this story as "Castaway" by Edmond Hamilton, having given it a quick perusal, I concur.  Here are the covers of the books containing this story. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?63159  "So, I came from Aarn, did I?  Then why don't I remember it?"  "You do, a little.  You remember the place almost.  You remember the names--almost.  You put them into your stories and poems."  I have two of the books this story appears in, which is probably why I couldn't tag it to a particular cover.

Answer (score 2):

Is it [*Death's Door: An Edgar Allan Poe Time Travel Novella*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1946161160) by April White?

> In the fall of 1849, Edgar Allan Poe disappeared. He was missing for five days, and was then found wandering near Gunnar's Hall in Baltimore, delirious and possibly drunk, wearing strange clothes and carrying a cane. Poe died four days later in a Baltimore hospital, never having regained proper consciousness except to call out for a mysterious person by the name of “Reynolds.”
>
> Of course Poe was a Clocker, and I knew I would write that story someday. What I hadn't expected was who would find Poe when he stumbled into the 21st Century.
>
> Her name is Alexandra "Ren" Reynolds, and she has a secret too.

It seems to be part of a series, and there are some reviews of it on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53537029-death-s-door). I couldn't find much info about it online, but it was the top result when I searched the web for `short story "edgar allan poe" "time travel"`.

Comment: Sorry no. In the story I am looking for one of the time traveller's friends/wife is trying to rescue him or actually his personality by reminding him of his own previous (future?) life. She takes over the body of a nineteenth century woman to try and jog his memory. As she fails she gives up and abandons the body. The woman is confused and Poe remarks on how her intelligent eyes have become dull and stupid. The title of the story makes reference to one of Poe's poems about a future utopian city.

Comment: @Frank Please [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/250146/edit) those details into your question - it can help other people to identify the story more easily :-)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not "The Man Who Collected Poe" by Robert Bloch, but I know I've read this one too.   Could that title reference be to "El Dorado"?

Comment: Thank you guys. I read this story back in the 1970's in an anthology that included various authors. None of my sci-fi fan acquaintances seem to have read it and I haven't been able to find it thru various Google searches. It's such a great premise that I would write it myself if everyone else has forgotten it . Looked up April White and some of her novels seem interesting specially Death's Door and An Urchin of Means. I already downloaded Bloch's The Man Who Collected Poe too. You can tell I love steampunk!